# C++ script on Spark Cluster throws exit status 132

Tags: pipe, c++, exit-status

I'm trying to run a c++ program on spark cluster by using the rdd.pipe() operation but the executors throw:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Subprocess exited with status 132.

The spark jar runs totally fine on standalone and the c++ program runs just fine on its own as well.
I've tried with another simple c++ script and there is no problem with it running on the cluster.

As i understand it the number 132 means Illegal Instruction but i don't know how to use this to pinpoint the source of this error.

I get no further info by checking the executor logs.

Comment: Is the cluster homogenous? Is every cluster node the same in architecture and system configuration?

Comment: Yes it has the same system configuration and here is some information on the cluster:

13 x Dell PowerEdge R300 Quad Core Xeon X3323 2.5GHz, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD
3 x Dell PowerEdge R310 Quad Core Xeon X3440 2.53GHz, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD
3 x Dell PowerEdge R310 Quad Core Xeon X3440 2.53GHz, 16GB RAM, 500GB HDD
3 x Dell PowerEdge R320 Intel Xeon E5-2430 v2 2.50GHz, 32GB RAM, 1TB HDD
1 x Dell PowerEdge R320 Intel Xeon E5-2430 v2 2.50GHz, 32GB RAM, 2 x 1TB HDD